# How do windows phone app orientation work?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, orientation

I am trying to make my first app using XNA, and I am having some issues with orientation and coordinates.

By default, my phone emulator is in portrait mode, but (0,0) is in the top right corner, and X and Y seem to be switched. from how I would expect them to be (x goes up, y goes across)

In my code, I try changing the orientation something similar to

```
SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;
SupportedOrientations.FullScreen = true;
```

And when I do this, it fixes the coordinate problems I am having, but then the screen becomes just a little square.

any ideas how to fix this? is this just how it is supposed to be?

Also, does orientation change automatically, or do I need to explicitly add

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanging
   (object sender,OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to mandating the valid orientations, you should set your PreferredBackBufferWidth and PreferredBackBufferHeight appropriately (480 and 800, respectively, for current WP7). These are both found in the `graphics` member of the main Game class. You don't need to manually set the orientation.

Comment: Awesome!! graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight does exactly what I want. Thanks!